# Problem appending to a list inside a loop using np.random.shuffle()

Tags: python, loops, append, shuffle

I am stuck in the following code, where I want to shuffle a list desired number of times and then store the result in a place while being inside a loop. I can see that inside the loop the shuffling is properly performed but I am unable to get the same result stored in the list.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
class shuffle():
     def __init__(self,arr,i):
         new=[]                                                                                                                                                 
         for ii in range(i):                 
             np.random.shuffle(arr)
             print arr
             new.append(arr)             
         self.new2 = np.asarray(new)
     def f():
         #print self.new2
         return self.new2

a = np.linspace(1,4,10)
s=shuffle(a,3)
```

input 'a' is

```
[1.        , 1.33333333, 1.66666667, 2.        , 2.33333333,
       2.66666667, 3.        , 3.33333333, 3.66666667, 4.        ])
```

the print output inside the class (shuffled 3 times) gives:

```
print arr

[2.         1.66666667 4.         1.         3.33333333 2.33333333
 3.66666667 1.33333333 3.         2.66666667]
[2.33333333 2.         1.33333333 1.66666667 3.66666667 1.
 3.33333333 3.         2.66666667 4.        ]
[2.         3.66666667 2.33333333 4.         1.66666667 1.33333333
 3.         3.33333333 2.66666667 1.        ]
```

But the array output 'new2' gives the following result instead of the expected above output :

```
s.new2
Out[15]: 
array([[2.        , 3.66666667, 4.        , 3.33333333, 2.33333333,
        2.66666667, 1.        , 1.33333333, 3.        , 1.66666667],
       [2.        , 3.66666667, 4.        , 3.33333333, 2.33333333,
        2.66666667, 1.        , 1.33333333, 3.        , 1.66666667],
       [2.        , 3.66666667, 4.        , 3.33333333, 2.33333333,
        2.66666667, 1.        , 1.33333333, 3.        , 1.66666667]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the solution is, thanks to @a_guest 's answer

```
class shuffle():
    ...:      def __init__(self,arr,i):
    ...:          new=[]                                                                                                                                         
    ...:         
    ...:          for ii in range(i):                 
    ...:              arr2=arr.copy()
    ...:              np.random.shuffle(arr2)
    ...:              print arr2
    ...:              new.append(arr2)             
    ...:          self.new2 = np.asarray(new)
    ...:      def f():
    ...:          #print self.new2
    ...:          return self.new2
```

The output now is as expected :

```
s.new2
Out[34]: 
array([[3.        , 1.        , 3.66666667, 2.66666667, 1.66666667,
        2.33333333, 1.33333333, 4.        , 2.        , 3.33333333],
       [4.        , 3.66666667, 3.        , 2.33333333, 1.66666667,
        1.33333333, 2.66666667, 1.        , 3.33333333, 2.        ],
       [2.        , 3.        , 2.33333333, 4.        , 3.33333333,
        1.        , 1.66666667, 1.33333333, 2.66666667, 3.66666667]])
```

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned [`np.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) will modify the array in-place. Since you append the array itself (actually a reference to it) to the `new` list, in the end it contains three references to the same array (containing values from the last shuffling). Try printing `[id(x) for x in s.new2]` to convince yourelf. Instead you can append a copy via `new.append(arr.copy())`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So this is what the solution should be :   
new.append(arr.copy())  
instead of 
new.append(arr) 
 ?